# C# - Edit Form Label using Static Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, non-static

```
public static void Monitor0()
    {
        bool ToMineOrNot = Backend.ToMineOrNot;
        while (ToMineOrNot)
        {
            Form1 temp = new Form1();
            Form1.NonStaticDelegate = new Action(temp.setHashRate);
            Form1.NonStaticDelegate();
            Backend.hps = 0;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        if (ToMineOrNot == false)
        {

        }
    }
    public void setHashRate()
    {
        hashrate.Text = Backend.hps.ToString();
    }
```

I have to get the Static Void to call the non Static Void, i have to have Monitor0 Static because it has to be Run in a Thread, and setHashRate() has to be Non-static to edit the label (It's a Windows form):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(Monitor0);
thread.Start();
```

Does anybody know how i could Do that? and I cant just do this because the label won't be changed:

`Form1 form = new Form();
form.label1.Text = "text"`

Comment: What about passing the form into your static function: monitor0(Form1 temp)

Comment: This Code is in A Form, so I dont know if that would do Really Much.

Comment: Have the function take a form1 argument, if you call monitor0 inside a form use this as a parameter

Comment: that wouldnt work because monitor(Form1 form1){ form1.setHashRate()} //error

Comment: whats the error? or can you elaborate more on when or where monitor0() is being called

Comment: thats what i could understand, and that won't work: public static void Monitor0(Form form1)
        {
            bool ToMineOrNot = Backend.ToMineOrNot;
            while (ToMineOrNot)
            {
                form1.setHashRate();
                Backend.hps = 0;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            if (ToMineOrNot == false)
            {
                
            }
        }

Comment: Where does Monitor0() get called? Also make sure its Monitor0(Form1 form1) Since thats the class that should have the setHashRate()

Comment: In the Thread, Thread thread = new Thread(Monitor0);
thread.Start(); (a bit before in the Code, basically i have a PictureBox and if its Clicked that Bit of Code Happens. and Since its a Thread, Monitor0 has to be a Static)

Comment: I need to be an instance of the form (not static).  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net